# New File via Dropbox Does Not Inherit Windows Directory Permissions

Tags: macos, file-permissions, dropbox, windows-server-2012, acl

Environment:
Windows Server 2012
Mac OS 10.6.8
Dropbox

The purpose of the Dropbox share is to allow the user on the Mac to move files into a directory that is served by IIS on the Windows Server machine.

The shared folder has the proper permissions for IIS to be able to read and serve the files (tested with existing files). Examining the root shared folder under folder properties => Security => Advanced, inheritance is turned on (the current button reads "Disable Inheritance"). This is to ensure that new files have the proper permissions for serving.

When the Mac user creates a new folder on their local machine inside the Dropbox shared folder, it is successfully created on the Windows Server with the proper permissions and inheritance on. However, when the Mac user creates an image in that directory (in this test, via copy-paste), on the Windows Server it is created with only System, Administrator, and Administrators permissions with inheritance turned off.

What I want is for these new files to have inheritance turned on, or at the very least, created with a specific set of permissions. What are my solution options? I figure there are three courses: find a way to configure Dropbox to do this, find a way to have Windows overrule what Dropbox is doing, or find a tool that will automatically scan and fix permissions in this directory (via schedule or live monitoring).

Thanks.